# Angular 5 material flex-layout fxLayoutAlign="space-evenly center" not working

Tags: css, flexbox, angular5, angular-material2, angular-flex-layout

I am using Angular 5 & material themes, I am trying to space out some sibling form inputs to look [like this](https://tburleson-layouts-demos.firebaseapp.com/#/docs)

The link above advise to use a div like this one:

```
div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-evenly center"
```

I tried to use this in my app but it doesn't space them out, please check out [this stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-npvkhk?file=app/app.component.html) for a complete view of the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [npm page of the @angular/flex-layout](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/flex-layout), it wasn't mentioned that we need to import the module in app.module so I assumed it might be enabled by default in angular like some other core angular modules

However as per this [page](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/Fast-Starts) , we need to import it as follows:

To use the @angular/flex-layout, you have to:

1- install it using npm

```
npm i @angular/flex-layout --save
```

2- Import it in the app.module file of the angular app for it to work

Whilst this is basic for most of the modules, I didn't see it in the demo so I forgot it.

In **app.module.ts**, you have to import it as follows:

```
import { FlexLayoutModule } from "@angular/flex-layout";

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, BrowserAnimationsModule, MatFormFieldModule, MatInputModule,
  FlexLayoutModule
  ],
```

[**a full stackblitz example is here**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zn8xzy?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Note:

I was about to post this question, but then I found out the solution & I thought to share it to help someone else having similar issue